# How to calculate a div's width and make all their sibilings adopt the biggest size so that they look consistent using CSS?

Tags: css

I want to make several divs containing diferent strings () length inside. I want them to fit to the content, but this pose a problem: one of the various divs will contain a larger string, hence, It will be bigger in width than the others, and when applying a border, it looks awful.

I've been practicing some HTML and CSS in jsbin and did this code:

```css
html,body{
  padding:0!important;
  margin:0!important;
}

.padre{
  border:2px solid violet;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -o-fit-content;
  width:-webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="padre">
    <div class="hijo">
      <h4 id="gato">El gato.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <h4 id="gato">La Firefox.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <h4>El gato pulpo.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <h4>La turritopsis nutrícula.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="padre">
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4 id="gato">El perro.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4 id="gato">La vaca.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4>El lobo aguila.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4>La caravana h.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="padre">
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4 id="gato">El mono.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4 id="gato">La dragon.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4>La serpiente.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4>El caballo.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

:

But as you can see, they don't look consistent because I'm using `width:fit-content` instead of a fixed width.

Is there a way using pure CSS to calculate the biggest div's width and apply that width to others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all of them inside an `inline-block` element

```css
html,body{
  padding:0!important;
  margin:0!important;
}

.padre{
  border:2px solid violet;
  
}
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  /*
  OR display:table
  OR float:left
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="padre">
    <div class="hijo">
      <h4 id="gato">El gato.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <h4 id="gato">La Firefox.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <h4>El gato pulpo.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="hijo">
      <h4>La turritopsis nutrícula.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="padre">
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4 id="gato">El perro.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4 id="gato">La vaca.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4>El lobo aguila.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4>La caravana h.</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="padre">
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4 id="gato">El mono.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4 id="gato">La dragon.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4>La serpiente.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hijo">
        <h4>El caballo.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in css:

```
.hijo {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: css drove/drives me nuts sometimes too.  makes me overlook simple solutions for fear they won't work...